# Is it possible to stream music over a bluetooth p2p connection using iPhones

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, p2p

I am trying to connect multiple iPhones using bluetooth. I was thinking of having a server/client system. I just want to know upto how many devices can be connected using bluetooth? I am not able to find a reliable answer online.

Also If you know of any good tutorials regarding this it would great if you could point me to it.

Thanks
AC

Answer (score 0):

A single Bluetooth device can connect with upto 7 devices in a piconet. If a device can do scatternet it can be connected to even more devices..

Application level connection can happen only if both devices supports the required profiles and corresponding role.
If you are trying to stream music , the profile to be used is A2DP , one device will need to be the A2DP source and other A2DP sink, 
In case of Iphone it supports only A2DP source. So 2 iPhone will not connect with each other.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement the bluetooth profile for this (A2DP), the big issue here is not the music streaming but the roles, you iPhones are going to play, for instance, you can be a "sound-source" and transfer audio to a "sound-sink" device, those roles have to be previously defined on the handshake and paring action, furthermore, if you are able to browse the properties of an iPhone you will get what port and what roles are supported, sadly muss I said, there is no sink role supported jet for iPhones, so the most that you can get till now is stream audio from iPhone to another bt capable device (speakers, pc, headset unit, etc) more info can be reached on the official bluetooth web site and what [iOS](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647) until now supports.